# Get Shared Preferences Value using Provider State Management

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences, flutter-provider

I try to Get Value from SharedPrefereces but I get a `null` value if I try to get Data in Main Page, I try to get the data when the state on the main page is created but I sometimes get null like this Available URL: http://169.172.70.108:8008/api/v1/iksk/self?idtraining=null

but after hot reload I managed to get the result like this

Available URL: http://169.172.70.208:8008/api/v1/iksk/self?idtraining=2021-01-21

this is my code

```dart
@override
  void initState() {
    // get pelatihan
    MySharedPreferences.instance
        .getStringValue(key: 'namaPelatihan')
        .then((value) {
      namaPelatihan = value;

      // get nama Peserta
      MySharedPreferences.instance
          .getStringValue(key: 'namaPeserta')
          .then((value) {
        namaPeserta = value;
      });
    });
```

how do I get real-time results (get results when redirecting to the main page) using provider state management?

Answer (score 1):

first create a function then use async and await with it
then fellow this code

```
_transitionToNextPageAfterSplash() async {
    final auth = await SharedPreferences.getInstance()
        .then((value) => value.getBool('auth') ?? false);
}
```

Comment: after getting data from new shared preferences in redirect?

Comment: @perymerdeka i dont get what u are saying